# Laravel Route Model Binding Error

Tags: php, laravel, binding, model, routes

I'm developing an application using Laravel and simultaneously going through the Laravel tutorial to learn the various areas of this framework.

In web.php, I have a route:

```
    Route::get('/events/{event}', 'EventController@show');
```

In the Eventcontroller, I have the following:

```
    public function show($id) {
        $event = Event::find($id);
        return $event;
    }
```

And it works fine.  When I try and change it to the following format to clean up the code:

```
    public function show(Event $event) {
        return $event;
    }
```

I'm getting the error:
Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\EventController::show(App\Event $event) should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::show($id)

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: You're likely extending base class which has `show` method and has different structure. Just don't extend it or create another method.

Comment: The EventController does extend Controller, but that's provided by default from the Laravel installation.   The laracast (https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/9) shows this as possible without seeming to do anything special.

Comment: Have you solved it? Otherwise, have you declared a show method in your App\Http\Controllers\Controller?

Comment: The code "public function show(Event $event){ ... } now works as expected.  I do not, however, recall what, if anything, I may have been doing incorrectly at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter is not from the type int but Event, which fails.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do that you should add this line to your `RouteServiceProvider` class

`Route::model('event', App\Event::class);`

it is located in the app/providers.

[larvel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing)

Comment: Based on reading the documentation, I see how this should work (and will try it shortly).  But this is explicit model routing.  Given the name choices I've used for the variable and model name, shouldn't it work, implicitly?  
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#implicit-binding

Comment: Attempting to do what @Begmuhammet suggests results in this error:   Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\Users\Phil\Google Drive\EFCICO\Amazon-AWS\apache2\laravel\resources\views\v1\public_pages\display_event.blade.php)